# LED strip lighting joining cuts?

Tags: lighting, led

I bought some LED strip lighting and it just arrived:
http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00LXZKPWY/ref=ask_ql_qh_dp_hza

It's 5m but I only need about a metre so need to cut it to size. There are cut marks on it but how do I join the cuts?

I now noticed further down the page it shows other items and connectors, is that what I need? Apparently they'll take a month to deliver if I order which is awful, so is there any other way? Are these kind of things at electrical stores?

Comment: Solder on a small bit of wire to join sections together.   It's easy.

Comment: +1 to @trout. If they are silicone encased, try to cut the silicone away with a utility knife... bend the strip a little (imagine catching it with the side of your thumbnail) and cut lightly right at the junction of the silicone and the strip. With practice, you'll hit it just right and be able to peel the silicone back perfectly. See if your strip has solder joints every 50cm... you're much better off cutting on these points.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

For some LED strips once you cut the strip that's it.

That particular brand is linkable once it has been cut. It appears to be DC as opposed to AC so the link would require the correct polarity.

Looking at the product page it does not appear to show any link connectors, rather just the live ends (the part that feeds from the transformer).  But that is not to say it may or may not come with a couple of linkable connectors.

Some hardware stores stock basic LED strips like this but chances are they won't sell individual parts. And there is  a high probability it may be slightly off in size if you did find one that was a similar match. With the sensitivity of LEDs that could lead to the LED working part of the time or not working at all after it has been installed.

Comment: His LED strip is cuttable. The product page says _Cuttable and linkable. It can be cut every 3 LEDs along the cutting marks_